# From this code of Javascript, what is the password and how did you get it?

Tags: javascript

```
function a(val) {
let a = 500
let loc = window[arguments[0]];
for(let i = 0, a = 800; i < 5; i++) {
    debugger;
    for(a; a < 1000; a++) {
        debugger;
    }
}
console.log(a);
console.log((a / 100) - 3);
let p = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(loc).sort();
let href = p[p.indexOf("hash") + ((a / 100) - 2)];
return loc[href]
}

function check() {
let p = prompt("What is the password?");
let c = btoa(a("location") +btoa(arguments.callee) + btoa(a("location").split('/').toString()))
if(p == c) {
    console.log("Correct.")
}
}
```

From this Javascipt code, what would be the password.
For sure the password is from this line

```
let c = btoa(a("location") +btoa(arguments.callee) + btoa(a("location").split('/').toString()))
```

Answer (score 1):

The «password» will depend on the `location` of the page where this script is run. Without knowing that, it is impossible to tell.

---

Regardless, let's run it and find out what the password is for *this* very page on StackOverflow:

```js
function a(val) {
  let a = 500
  let loc = window[arguments[0]];
  for (let i = 0, a = 800; i < 5; i++) {
    //debugger;
    for (a; a < 1000; a++) {
      //debugger;
    }
  }
  //console.log(a);
  //console.log((a / 100) - 3);
  let p = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(loc).sort();
  let href = p[p.indexOf("hash") + ((a / 100) - 2)];
  return loc[href]
}

function check() {
  let p = "" //prompt("What is the password?");
  let c = btoa(a("location") + btoa(arguments.callee) + btoa(a("location").split('/').toString()))
  if (p == c) {
    console.log("Correct.")
  }
  return c; /* Only thing added is this return statement */
}

console.log(check());
```

Comment: This is more of a comment rather than answer mate. and it must be posted as comment not as answer